# Why I get the error 'ln: failed to create symbolic link '?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to install `casperjs` from git by the manual http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/installation.html#installing-from-git
but I get the error

> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/bin/casperjs’: No such file or directory

What can I do in this case? My operating system is Windows 8.

Comment: The command "ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs" is for linux system valid not for windows. You have to set the enviroment variable in Windows and add casperjs/bin directory to the path. For further information, this article is the right place http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'l try this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create symbolic link on Windows. Just add CasperJS bin directory to the %[PATH% environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows8)

Answer (score 0):

The command "ln -sf pwd/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs" is for linux system valid not for windows. 
 
You have to set the enviroment variable in Windows and add casperjs/bin directory to the path. For further information, this article is the right place https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Answer (score 0):

The **filesystem** where you're trying to create the link (not point to, but the link itself) must support these types of links.

For example, **ext3**, and **btrfs** support these links, but **ntfs** (like what you typically find on a USB stick) does not.

In other words you can have this trouble on Linux just as well as on windows.